# Verifying a Construction Satisfies the $\Omega$-axiom.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I'm stuck on [Exercise 4.5.1 of Goldblatt's, "*Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic*"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLPDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=topoi+verify+this+construction+satisfies+the+axiom+%22topoi%22&source=bl&ots=qRfIE5YNRc&sig=VBlHXO0I_3kXiMri_EBbAn_fSN0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BpekU7j8DYGr0gWj8YDoCA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=topoi%20verify%20this%20construction%20satisfies%20the%20axiom%20%22topoi%22&f=false).

It's in the topos $\mathbf{Bn}(I)$ of [bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(mathematics)) over a set $I$. Goldblatt asks the reader to verify that

[image]$\tag{1}$

satisfies the $\Omega$-axiom.${}^\dagger$ The construction is defined in the first link above.

For convenience: here $(A, f)\stackrel{k}{\rightarrowtail}(B, g)$ is an arbitrary, monic $\mathbf{Bn}(I)$-arrow, taken as an inclusion; $(I, \operatorname{id}_I)$ is the terminal object in $\mathbf{Bn}(I)$; $p_I$ is the projection $p_I(\langle x, y\rangle)=y$; $\top$ is defined by $\top(i)=\langle 1, i\rangle$; and $\chi_k$ is the *product map* $\langle\chi_A, g\rangle$, i.e., $$\chi_k(x)=\begin{cases}\langle 1, g(x)\rangle &: x\in A \\ \langle 0, g(x)\rangle &: x\notin A.\end{cases}$$

**Thoughts:** What I've done so far is replace $\chi_k$ with an arbitrary $\mathbf{Bn}(I)$-arrow $h: \langle B, g\rangle\to \langle 2\times I, p_I\rangle$ in $(1)$, supposing what I get is a pullback. Then I've run it though the definition of a pullback quite easily. I've had numerous stupid ideas about what to do next (with all manner of confusing diagrams) but to no avail.

> I'd like a detailed solution, please.

It **should** be easier than I think it is. Maybe my problem is with bundles themselves. This is my second attempt at reading Goldblatt's book: last time I thought I had'm but got up to "**11.4: Models in a Topos**" - *right where I wanted to be* - before other commitments made me lose track entirely; now I'm about to read "**4.8: $\Omega$ and comprehension**".

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: The $\Omega$-axiom is given on page 81, ibid., via the definition of a [subobject classifier](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject+classifier):

> **Definition:** If $\mathbb{C}$ is a category with a terminal object $1$, then a *subobject classifier* for $\mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-object $\Omega$ with a $\mathbb{C}$-arrow $\text{true}: 1\to\Omega$ that satisfies the following axiom.
>
> **$\Omega$-axiom:** For each monic $f:a\rightarrowtail d$ there is one and only one $\mathbb{C}$-arrow $\chi_{f}:d\to\Omega$ such that $\chi_f\circ f=\text{true}\circ !$ is a pullback square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
First, recall that $\mathbf{Bn}(I)$ is just a notation for the slice category $\mathsf{Set}_{/I}$.

> **Lemma.** For any category $\mathscr C$ and any object $c$ of $\mathscr C$, the forgetful functor $\mathscr C_{/c} \to \mathscr C$ commutes with fibered products.

So if you have a pullback as in your question, the square 
$$ \begin{CD}
A @>k>> B \\
@VfVV @VV\chi_k V \\
I @>>\top> 2 \times I
\end{CD} $$ 
is a pullback in $\mathsf{Set}$.
Then, remark that the square
$$ \begin{CD}
I @>\top>> 2\times I \\
@VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>\mathrm{true}> 2
\end{CD} $$ 
is also a pullback ($\mathrm{true}$ being the map selecting $1 \in 2$).
So, concatenating the two squares makes the outer square of
$$ \begin{CD}
A @>k>> B \\
@VfVV @VV\chi_k V \\
I @>>\top> 2 \times I \\
@VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>\mathrm{true}> 2
\end{CD} $$ 
a pullback again. But then $2$, equipped with the map $\mathrm{true} \colon 1 \to 2$, is a subobject classifier for $\mathsf{Set}$. From here, you can easily derive the uniqueness of $\chi_k$ (remember that $p_I \circ \chi_k$ is fixed to be $g$ by hypothesis).

Comment: Thank you, @Pece. I had to make sure I can understand this without recourse to functors, though, given the way Goldblatt has structured his book; I can just about see what you've done :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to fill in the gaps of the great answer above.  Understand how PBL (pullback lemma) works in Goldblatt.  And understand that for products there exists a unique arrow $\langle p, q \rangle$ for any third object $a \xleftarrow{p} c \xrightarrow{q} b$ onto the argument objects (of the product).

[image: Bn(I) Omega axiom satisfied picture]

Note that $! \circ f = !$ and that in set $\chi_A$ is already known to exist (regardless of uniqueness) since $\textbf{Set}$ has a subobject classifier $\Omega$.  Thus after pasting the two pullbacks, you get a pullback diagram on the right (the square).  But more importantly, we know that the morphism $\chi_A$ is the unique such morphism that creates that pullback square by the $\Omega$ axiom in $\text{Set}$.

Thus $\chi_k = \langle m, g \rangle$ where $m = \chi_A$.  Now apply the product rule to the object $B$ with its two projectors onto the arguments of $2 \times I$, namely $\chi_A : B \to 2$ and $g:B\to I$.  Then by definition of $\langle \chi_A, g\rangle$ it is the unique such arrow (we call it $\chi_k$) such that $p_2 \circ \chi_k = \chi_A$ and $p_I \circ \chi_k = g$.  That's using the universal property of product.

But that is the same as saying it is the unique arrow such that the square on the top left (together with arrows into $I$) above is a pullback in $\text{Bn}(I)$ because one of the conditions that the whole thing commutes or in particular that $p_I \circ \chi_k = g$.

As is often the case in mathematics, we don't always make full use of a condition, i.e. we only said "such that $p_I \circ \chi_k = g$" and didn't mention all the other conditions going on in the pullback.  One condition was enough in this case.

Comment: It's a slight abuse of notation to write $!\circ f=!$, is it not?

Comment: @Shaun yes, that's correct.  ! is used anytime there's a unique something and we don't need to name it.