# Computing the truth values in $\mathbf{Set}^2$.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

This is part of **Exercise 4.5.2** of Goldblatt's, *"Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic"*.

### Context:

Here is an old question of mine on the preceding exercise:

[Verifying a Construction Satisfies the $\Omega$-axiom.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/841084/104041)

I have read Goldblatt's book before but didn't do all of its exercises. After struggling with the second set of exercises in Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic: [. . .],"* I have returned to Goldblatt (and this time I have a study buddy).

### The Question:

> Compute the truth values in $\mathbf{Set}^2$.

### Thoughts:

I remember doing this exercise before; from what I recall, with $\top:\{0\}\to 2=\{0,1\}$ being ${\rm true}:0\mapsto 0$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ and - because ${\rm false}$ is not yet defined in general in Goldblatt's book - the "other" truth value in $\textbf{Set}$ being given by $\bot: \{0\}\to 2, 0\mapsto 1$, because the product arrow $\langle \top, \top\rangle: \langle \{0\}, \{0\}\rangle\to \langle 2,2\rangle$ is the subobject classifier of $\mathbf{Set}^2$, and $\langle \top, \bot\rangle\simeq \langle \bot, \top\rangle^\dagger$, the truth values of $\mathbf{Set}^2$ are, up to isomorphism, the following:

- $\langle \top, \top\rangle$,
- $\langle \bot, \top\rangle$, and
- $\langle \bot, \bot\rangle$.

But I'm not sure. I'm confused about the details. How do I prove that the candidate truth values are what I'm after?

The exercise in question was easy enough for me the first time I read Goldblatt, as indicated by the very next question I asked being

[Epic-monic factorisation in $\mathbf{Set}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/844575/104041)

about **Exercise 5.2.1** just three days after **Exercise 4.5.1**.

I think I'm losing my mind.

---

I'm aware that

$${\rm Sub}(1_{\mathbf{Set}^2})\cong \mathbf{Set}^2(1_{\mathbf{Set}^2}, \Omega_{\mathbf{Set}^2}),$$

where the latter is the set of truth values of $\mathbf{Set}^2$.

***I think what I have so far is nonsense.***

Please help :)

---

$\dagger:$ Is this right?

Comment: You know you're looking for all the maps from the terminal object of $\mathbf{Set}^2$ to $\Omega_{\mathbf{Set}^2}$, and you know the latter is the pair $\langle 2,2\rangle$. What is the terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}^2$? Once you're clear on that-simply compute what all the maps are. I'm not sure what the work involving $\dagger$ is saying, but it's not the most straightforward solution and your answer isn't quite correct.

Comment: Total aside, but it might be more clear to write $\mathbf{Set}^{\times 2}$, since $\mathbf{Set}^2$ can also mean the arrow category of $\mathbf{Set}$, because some authors use $2$ to denote the category with $2$ objects and a single non-identity arrow between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working in $\text{Set}^2$ elements are essentially pairs of set elements in usual math.  Therefore the truth values or $\text{Set}^2(\{(0,0)\}, \{0,1\}^2) \simeq \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ (granted this isomorphism is in $\textbf{Set}$, but I guess you can identify objects & arrows in $\textbf{Set}^2$ with a full subcategory of $\textbf{Set}$).  No need to check for isomorphisms between the truth values according to Goldblatt's book.